# cambiar imagen aleatoria de un div cada que hay un refresh (F5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

tengo la siguiente duda para cambiar una imagen con *JS*, tengo el siguiente código.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<script >
    var imagen_random = new Array();
    imagen_random[0] = "images/1.png";
    imagen_random[1] = "images/2.png";
    imagen_random[2] = "images/3.png";
    imagen_random[3] = "images/4.png";
    imagen_random[4] = "images/5.png";
    imagen_random[5] = "images/6.png";

    function cargar_imagen_random(){
       var azar = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagen_random.length);
       document.images["random"].src = imagen_random[azar];
    }
</script>
<body onload="cargar_imagen_random()" >
    <!-- Primer div -->
    <div><img src="images/inicio.png" height="150px" /></div>

    <!-- Segundo div -->
    <div><img src="images/inicio.png" name="random" height="150px" /></div>

    <!-- Tercer div -->
    <div><img src="images/inicio.png" name="random" height="150px" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Todos los div tienen una imagen con el que inicia, hasta ahí todo bien, al agregar el atributo **"name=random"** en los dos últimos div y al refrescar la pagina (F5) solo me cambia en el **segundo div** y el *tercer div* permanece igual sin ningún cambio de imagen.

luego agregué la siguiente linea en el scrript

```
document.images["random2"].src = objetos[azar];
Y en el tercer div cambie el nombre a name="random2"
```

y obtuve como resultado que sí se actualizaba, pero la idea es que la imagen sea aleatoria y no se repita la misma imagen en los div, sino **aleatoria**, y no estar agregando otro linea en el script sino sea automáticamente así tenga "X" DIV.

por favor su apoyo, quien pueda ayudarme con esto muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿y si primero desordenas el array y luego las adjudicas por orden? asi te evitas que la imagen salga repetida.
1º desordenas el array (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/402281/cambiar-imagen-aleatoria-de-un-div-cada-que-hay-un-refresh-f5)
2º metes en un for las imagenes name = random.
3º Les adjudicas el elemento i del array
¿Que tal se entiende?

Comment: muchas gracias por tu apoyo, en la respuesta de abajo encontré la solución solo hice un pequeño cambio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es, por cada imagen generar el número aleatorio y llamar a la función pasándole ese número. Para eso necesitas capturar todas las imágenes y recorrerlas con un bucle.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<script >
    var imagen_random = new Array();
    imagen_random[0] = "images/1.png";
    imagen_random[1] = "images/2.png";
    imagen_random[2] = "images/3.png";
    imagen_random[3] = "images/4.png";
    imagen_random[4] = "images/5.png";
    imagen_random[5] = "images/6.png";

    function cargar_imagen_random(){
       //document.images["random"].src = imagen_random[azar];
       document.querySelectorAll('div > img').forEach(function (imagen) {
          var azar = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagen_random.length);
          imagen.src = imagen_random[azar];
       });
    }
</script>
<body onload="cargar_imagen_random()" >
    <!-- Primer div -->
    <div><img src="images/inicio.png" height="150px" /></div>

    <!-- Segundo div -->
    <div><img src="images/inicio.png" name="random" height="150px" /></div>

    <!-- Tercer div -->
    <div><img src="images/inicio.png" name="random" height="150px" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo probé y todo esta como quería, solo hice un pequeño cambio, como el primer div no queria que cambie la imagen, reemplace el ('div > img') por ('#random') y en el segundo y tercer div en la etiqueta img le agregue un id="random), de esa manera obtuve lo que quería. Gracias.